# PHP mail() Return-Path Issues

Tags: php, email

After moving to new hosting, I've started having strange issues.

PHP mail() function only works, if I add the following line to php.ini with -f parameter.
(If I omit -f parameter, mail() function will return true, but do nothing.)

```
[mail function]
  sendmail_path = "/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i -f email@mydomain.com"
```

This, however, causes all messages have the following undesirable header:

```
Return-Path: <email@mydomain.com>
```

I've tried adding fifth argument to mail(), however it has no effect.

I would highly appreciate your help.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check/change your PHP mail configuration:

Open your php.ini file (if you don't know where this is, see below) Search for the line that reads [mail function] Add/change the details of your mail server. This could be a local mail server or the mail server of your ISP. Save/close the php.ini file Restart your web server

An example of what the mail settings could look like when you first open the php.ini file:

```
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
SMTP = localhost
smtp_port = 25

; For Win32 only.
;sendmail_from = me@example.com

; For Unix only.  You may supply arguments as well (default: "sendmail -t -i").
;sendmail_path =
```

Additional info is in echoing `phpinfo()` you can view your PHP configuration details. You can do this by creating a .php file with the following line on it: . When you run this in your browser, you will see a full list of PHP configuration variables. Simply search for the lines that contain php.ini and sendmail_path to see the values you need to use.

Another idea is you might use `ini_set()` to properly config your mail setting like this

Add the following code to the top of your email script if your mail script continues to fail.

```
// Please specify your Mail Server - Example: mail.example.com.
ini_set("SMTP","mail.example.com");

// Please specify an SMTP Number 25 and 8889 are valid SMTP Ports.
ini_set("smtp_port","25");

// Please specify the return address to use
ini_set('sendmail_from', 'example@YourDomain.com');
```